# Does Paypal or Stripe support multi-payer payments?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments

I am looking for a payment processor that supports N-Payer->1-Payee.

As documented https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#payment_create,

users make payment requests by providing the server with a *payment* object.  Within the object, there is a *payer* field which specifies the source of the funds for the payment.

Answer (score 2):

(Disclaimer: I work for Stripe.)

Stripe does not support this directly -- you'd have to [create as many charges](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) as there are payers.

Due to the way card payments work, I'd guess that all card processors have the same limitation, though maybe other processors have built features to better handle such payment flows.